# VBA is it possible to pass a Dictionary/Collection to an autofilter?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, collections, autofilter

The idea was to create a variable that would save the changes made to it from previous use of the macro. I have a userform that pulls values from a range and populates unique values in a listbox. I then want to be able to add selected values to my dictionary/collection and save the change. Once all necessary changes have been made, the macro should use the dictionary variable as criteria for an autofilter.

My question is two fold, what class should I use to accomplish this? How can a use this variable to autofilter my worksheet? Userform code is below:

The First bit of code is for the "Add" command button. It is supposed to take the selected value(s) in the listbox and add them to the dictionary titled "Market". The code after that pulls the values from a recently opened excel workbook an displays unique values in the listbox. Listbox2 holds all previous values from past uses of the macro. I want to add a "Delete" button to the userform to tidy up the list if necessary. The two public variables below are actually located on the main macro module, this would allow me to store the values in the dictionary after the userform has stopped running.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        Market.Add ListBox1.List(i)
        Set Market = New Collection
    End If
Next


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim myList As Collection
 Dim myRange As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim myVal As Variant
 Dim Col As Integer

 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Unconfirmed")
 Col = WorksheetFunction.Match("Marketer", ws.Range("3:3"), 0)
 Set myRange = ws.Range(Cells(4, Col), Cells(4, Col).End(xlDown))
 Set myList = New Collection
 On Error Resume Next

 For Each mycell In myRange.Cells
     myList.Add mycell.Value, CStr(mycell.Value)
 Next mycell
 On Error GoTo 0

 For Each myVal In myList
     Me.ListBox1.AddItem myVal
 Next myVal
```

Public item As Variant
Public Market As Collection

```
Market.Add "Al D"
Market.Add "B Collins"
Market.Add "B G"
Market.Add "C Huter"

For Each item In Market
    Me.ListBox2.AddItem item
Next item

End Sub
```

Comment: You can pass a dictionary's `.Keys()` or `.Values()`, or you can pass a vector array, but I don't think you can directly pass a collection to the `.List` property, you have to do the `For Each` iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **AutoFilter** runs from an *array,* I would build the array dynamically and use it in a filtering sub:

```
Dim ary()

Sub MAIN()
    Call BuildDynamicArray
    Call FilterMyData
End Sub

Sub BuildDynamicArray()
    Dim inString As String
    i = 1
    While 1 = 1
        x = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a value", Type:=2)
        If x = False Then GoTo out
        ReDim Preserve ary(1 To i)
        ary(i) = x
        i = i + 1
    Wend
out:
End Sub

Sub FilterMyData()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```